# What's the proper use of scoped variables in powershell?

Tags: powershell

The way I've been writing code is that I've been making separate ps1 files to do specific tasks.  In doing so I noticed that a script in one file has access to the variables of the calling script.

For my limited purposes, I don't think I'll ever want to have globals as I want each ps1 file to act as a function which is passed the arguments it needs.

Should I be defining a scope for every variable I create?  Is there a way to force all variables in a ps1 file to be local in scope?  Or do I need to set the scope on each variable?

EDIT (Untested simplified code to demonstrate):

The second file will print $month from the first file.  This means it's a global and not local just to file1.ps1.  I don't want globals as I'd rather pass what I need the other scripts need.  Should file2.ps have been defined as a function to prevent this?

```
file1.ps1:

$date = Get-Date
$month = $date.Month

./file2.ps1

---------------------
file2.ps1:

write-host $month

=================================
```

Comment: Could we see some source code for clarity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any variable will be created automatically in a local scope unless you declare it to a specific scope. `Script` is the local scope for commands in the base of a script file, and function is a a local scope of commands inside a function. Global is the "local scope" for the sessions (ex. commands your write directly in the console). Ex:

MyScript.ps1

```
$myscriptvar = "This is in a local SCRIPT scope"

function test {
    $myfuncvar = "This is in the local scope for the function"
    #I can READ $myscriptvar in here, but if I define it (ex $myscriptvar = 2), 
    #the change will exist in a LOCAL variable ($function:myscriptvar) in the function only.
}

test
```

Console

```
$myglobalvar = @"
This is in the global scope and can be read by 
the script and the function inside the script, but any changes will be saved in 
their local scope if not specified like $global:mygloblvar
"@

.\MyScript.ps1
```

So all variables is by default created in the "local" scope, it just depends where you define it (in console, scriptfile, function).

**EDIT** example with scripts:

Untitled2.ps1

```
"In script2, `$myvar is: $:myvar"
"In script2, `$script:myvar is: $script:myvar"
$myvar = "lol"
```

Untitled1.ps1

```
$myvar = "Hey"
.\Untitled2.ps1
$myvar
```

Console

```
PS > .\Untitled1.ps1
In script2 , $myvar is: Hey
In script2 , $script:myvar is:
Hey
```

Comment: What if I'm not actually creating functions?  Just ps1 files with parameters?  Is that why I have access to the calling scripts variables?  Was I supposed to actual make them functions?

Comment: The second script is in a local scope BELOW the first script (as script-scope is to global-scope). You can READ variables from the scope above, but when you try to set the value of the variable, it will be saved in a local variable(second script) with the same name. As I said in my samples. If you can get the value from the scope above, it means you haven't used that variable name in your second script. So why are you reading it if you don't want the value from the parent script? I can't understand your problem

Comment: The problem was as follows: I had an argument to my second file called $month.  this argument was also the name of a variable in the first file.  I then realized I didn't need that argument and removed it from the second file argument list but there was a reference to it left behind that ended up reading a value from the calling script.  It was at this point that I realized a script that was called had access to a variable in the calling script.

Comment: Okay. Well the solution is as you pointed out yourself, to just remove the old reference. A "debugging-rule" I use, is that if I recieve a value from a scope above(without expecting it), it means I screwed up somewhere(referencing a non-exisiting variable). If you for some reason just need to avoid these situations, you need to specify the scope every time you READ a variable(since it will read from parent scopes when the variable doesn't exists in the local scope). Ex: you should use `$script:month` in your `file2.ps1`

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think the most important aspect of your question has not been addressed: *scope pollution*.
Scope pollution is a very legitimate concern and may be even more troublesome than your example suggests. Consider the following two scripts

```
=========== script1.ps1 ============
$month = "jan"
$year = "1999"    
. .\script2.ps1    
"Date in script1 is {0}, {1}" -f $month, $year
=========== END script1.ps1 ============

=========== script2.ps1 ============
$year = "2013"
"Date in script2 is {0}, {1}" -f $month, $year
$month = "feb"
=========== END script2.ps1 ============
```

The output is this:

```
Date in script2 is jan, 2013
Date in script1 is feb, 2013
```

That is, not only does script2--the supposed "child"--have access to script1's variables but script1--the supposed "parent"--also has access to script2's variables! The reason for this is that dot-sourcing a script is not a parent-child relationship; the dot-sourced entity is on par with the dot-sourcing entity. It is as if the script was written

```
$month = "jan"
$year = "1999"
$year = "2013"
"Date in script2 is {0}, {1}" -f $month, $year
$month = "feb"
"Date in script1 is {0}, {1}" -f $month, $year
```

The fact that you recognize there is a scoping issue means you should at least be considering functions and modules for proper encapsulation. For further reading, take a look at a couple of my articles on Simple-Talk.com:

- [Down the Rabbit Hole: A Study in PowerShell Pipelines, Functions, and Parameters](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/down-the-rabbit-hole--a-study-in-powershell-pipelines,-functions,-and-parameters/)
- [Further Down the Rabbit Hole: PowerShell Modules and Encapsulation](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/further-down-the-rabbit-hole-powershell-modules-and-encapsulation/).

Answer (score 0):

In general, the default scope (i.e. with no modifiers) should almost always suffice, unless you need to override it with some other scope:

> An item you include in a scope is visible in the scope in which it 
>             was created and in any child scope, unless you explicitly make it 
>             private.

If you create a function, it will have its own scope.  Any variables you declare within the function will be limited to that scope (the inside of the function).

Comment: OK.  It seems dangerous but it makes sense.  My scripts are all simple enough that the normal scoping is fine, it just makes debugging slightly trickier.